# Create an universal java mapper for json string

Tags: java, json, converters

I'm working on a Spring-boot project where I receive different format of Json String. My goal is to convert these Json string into an Unified Java class.

I can receive many variations of this Json:

```
{ "id" : "someId", "type" : "temperature", "value" : 21.0 }
```

For example, one variation might look like :

```
{ "id" : "someId", "data" : { "type": "temp", "val" : 21.0 }, "location": "here" }
```

So these 2 Json must be mapped into the same Java class. 
I already have 2 solutions in mind :

**First solution**

1) Create a Specific Java Class for each Json that I may receive

2) Create a function that takes this specific object and return the Unified Java Class

**Second solution**

1) Create a JsonNode with the Json String

2) For each key try to match it with a field of the Unified Java Class.
But we have to take into consideration every key possible of a node like "value" or "val".

What is the best approach to solve this problem ?
I'm looking for a solution that could be easy to maintain.

**Edit** : I'm already using Jackson, but my problem is to map this Json object into an universal Java Class independently of the Json

**Edit 2** : The Unified Java Class is a class model that already exist and it's used to store information in our database. So to push information inside our database, I have to convert each json I receive into this unified format

Comment: See something like jackson https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: You're looking for a JSON library that can handle versioning.

Comment: I'm not looking for a json library (see Edit), but for a way to parse these Json object into an unique Java class, this class already exist and I can't change it

Comment: Can you tell us the context of this `Unified Java Class`? This has some bad smell on it if you ask me.

Comment: @HerrDerb see Edit 2

Comment: Can it be that these are two different versions of the client speaking to your API and the newer one delivers the data within a map `data`?

Comment: Yes, it's something like that. My application is receiving different json data from many sources and I have to convert these data to a specific java class regardless of the json structure

Answer (score 2):

I can see following solutions. E.g. you use `Jackson` for parse `JSON` you could declare you custom `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

This mapper contains additional options to ignore unknow properties.

1. Do you `Map<String, Object>` as destination class. This is `magic key` and it works always. **Contra**: you do not have json validation and have to add many constant keys to read this.

**Example:**

```
public static <T> Map<String, T> readMap(String json) throws NGPException {
    if (json == null) {
        return null;
    }

    ObjectReader reader = JSON_MAPPER.readerFor(Map.class);
    MappingIterator<Map<String, T>> it = reader.readValues(json);

    if (it.hasNextValue()) {
        Map<String, T> res = it.next();
        return res.isEmpty() ? Collections.emptyMap() : res;
    }

    return Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

**Client:**

```
Map<String, Object> map = readMap("json string");
String id = (String)map.getOrDefault("id", null);
```

1. Second way is to build **one general** class that contain all posiible variables. Additionnaly you have to set option to Jackson ignore unknown fields. In this case, existed fields will be used by Jackson.

**Example:**

```
public static <T> T read(String json, Class<T> clazz) throws NGPException {
    return mapper.readerFor(clazz).readValue(json);
}

class Response {
    private String id;
    private String type;
    private Double value;
    private String location;
    private Data data;

    public class Data {
        private String type;
        private String temp;
        private Double value;
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
Response response = read("json string", Response.class);
```

Comment: So after getting each field like your first example or the "Response" class of your second example, I still need to parse them into my "Universal Java Class". It seems a lot a work to maintain it, because we will have to modify your example and the mapping function

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [GSon](https://github.com/google/gson) from Google. It is really usefull. Check gson.fromJson(yourJsonString) in your case.

You can easy use

```
Gson gson = new Gson();    
Data data = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Data.class);
```

Comment: This wont help me, in your exemple, "jsonString" doesn't always match Data.class. My question is about an universal mapper for each type of jsonString into an unique Data.class

Comment: If Data.class has different attributes that are not comming in "jsonString", those params will be null. Also, jsonString may have more fields than Data.class has -will be ignored.

Comment: But we can't be sure that the name of attributes in Data.class match the name inside the jsonString. For example : The field "value" could also be named "val" and same for each fields